# Pyrax : This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested

Tags: python, django, pyrax

I am using Rackspace cloud storage for my media uploads and implemented with django-cumulus. The problem is that, file uploads are working well but when I tried to access my uploaded file with the container URI my browser shows an error as "This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.". Whether I need to change any setting for the container from my Rackspace account ?

Comment: Is the container enabled for public use?

Comment: s/enabled for public use/CDN enabled/

Comment: No it cannot be made public. But still the files have an assiciated URL in rackspace account which I can access through browser. Can I get the URL of the file just uploaded using pyrax?